# Flutter: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'int' has no instance method

Tags: flutter, api

My debug statement is displaying the database correctly, by after something is going wrong and in getting the error: Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class 'int' has no instance method '[]'. I am getting null data when I'm trying to display is in my application, this is because the list i am using to store the values has length 0

following is my class

```
class UserDetails extends ChangeNotifier {
  final String? userId;
  final String? mobileno;
  bool? userStatus;
  final String? adhar;
  final String? pan;
  final String? adharno;
  final String? panno;
  UserDetails(
      {this.userId,
      this.mobileno,
      this.userStatus = false,
      this.adhar,
      this.pan,
      this.adharno,
      this.panno});

}
```

following is my api where I am facing error

```
Future<void> getUsers(BuildContext context) async {
    final url = '${PurohitApi().baseUrl}${PurohitApi().users}';
    final List<UserDetails> loadedUsers = [];
    try {
      final client = RetryClient(
        http.Client(),
        retries: 4,
        when: (response) {
          return response.statusCode == 401 ? true : false;
        },
        onRetry: (req, res, retryCount) async {
          //print('retry started $token');

          if (retryCount == 0 && res?.statusCode == 401) {
            var accessToken = await Provider.of<Auth>(context, listen: false)
                .restoreAccessToken();
            // Only this block can run (once) until done

            req.headers['Authorization'] = accessToken;
          }
        },
      );
      var response = await client.get(
        Uri.parse(url),
        headers: {'Authorization': authToken!},
      );

      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      print(extractedData);
      if (extractedData['data'] == null) {
        return;
      }

      extractedData.forEach((userId, userData) {
        print(userId);
        loadedUsers.add(
          UserDetails(
            userId: userData['data']['id'],
            mobileno: userData['data']['mobileno'],
            userStatus: userData['data']['userstatus'],
            adhar: userData['data']['adhar'],
            pan: userData['data']['pan'],
            adharno: userData['data']['adharno'],
            panno: userData['data']['panno'],
          ),
        );
      });
      _users = loadedUsers.reversed.toList();
      //print(users);
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

I am facing NoSuchMethodError: Class 'int' has no instance method '[]'Tried calling: from above api following is my response
[image: this is my response]

Comment: could you print(userData); inside extractedData.forEach((userId, userData) and show the result?

Comment: this is userData inside forEach?

Comment: yeah it is in response from foreach

Answer (score 0):

I think userId should not be String, It should be an integer

```
    class UserDetails extends ChangeNotifier {
  final int? userId;
  final String? mobileno;
  bool? userStatus;
  final String? adhar;
  final String? pan;
  final String? adharno;
  final String? panno;
  UserDetails(
      {this.userId,
      this.mobileno,
      this.userStatus = false,
      this.adhar,
      this.pan,
      this.adharno,
      this.panno});

}
```

Comment: I had changed it but also facing same problem

Comment: see in which line you got this error, or please show me the complete of your error

Answer (score 0):

try to print your data in this error I think your data should be like userData['id'],

the above error is you try to use int as an object in the data returned

the returned userData is an int

Answer (score 0):

change this code :

```
extractedData.forEach((userId, userData) {
        print(userId);
        loadedUsers.add(
          UserDetails(
            userId: userData['data']['id'],
            mobileno: userData['data']['mobileno'],
            userStatus: userData['data']['userstatus'],
            adhar: userData['data']['adhar'],
            pan: userData['data']['pan'],
            adharno: userData['data']['adharno'],
            panno: userData['data']['panno'],
          ),
        );
      });
```

to this :

```
loadedUsers.add(
      UserDetails(
        userId: extractedData['data']['id'],
        mobileno: extractedData['data']['mobileno'],
        userStatus: extractedData['data']['userstatus'],
        adhar: extractedData['data']['adhar'],
        pan: extractedData['data']['pan'],
        adharno: extractedData['data']['adharno'],
        panno: extractedData['data']['panno'],
      ),
    );
```

the reason why :
`extractedData` is a `map<String,dynamic>`, when you call function `forEach(key, value)` :
the value is not a map, is an `Object`, or `dynamic`. the key is a `String`.
when you call this fuction :

```
value['data]
```

its will throw that error

if you `extractedData` is a List of Map, you can keep you original code, and change type of extractedData to List :

```
final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as List<Map<String, dynamic>>;
```

Edit :
your data in the response is a list Of a map so the code will be this :

```
final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String,dynamic>;
List<Map<String,dynamic>> data = extractedData['data'];
for (var map in data){
   loadedUsers.add(
      UserDetails(
        userId: map['id'],
        mobileno: map['mobileno'],
        userStatus: map['userstatus'],
        adhar: map['adhar'],
        pan: map['pan'],
        adharno: map['adharno'],
        panno: map['panno'],
      ),
    );
}
```

Comment: if I change it to list it is throwing error The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type at ['data']

Comment: can you provide us with your api response? its just a data type missmatch

Comment: I had updated the question with response

Comment: facing error on line.`List<Map<String,dynamic>> data = extractedData['data'];`_TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'